# Spring mapping resources for template Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, mapping, thymeleaf

Spring has problem with mapping items like css, js, img. Problem occured after when I clicked link from template index:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    return components.init("index",model).getHeader().getFooter().getSidebar().getRecommended().toString();
}
```

Link inside template the index looks like that: **/places/tags(parameters)**

```
@RequestMapping("/places/tags")
public String index(Model model,@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "eats", value="listOfTag") String listOfTag)   {
    System.out.println(listOfTag);
    return components.init("places",model).getHeader().getFooter().getSidebar().getPlaceForSidebar(listOfTag).toString();
}
```

After I clicked above link the places site looks not good.

Problem is with the mapping.

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/places/assets/css/styles.min.css]
```

I tried to register resources but nothing to change. I thinking that problem is on the site configuration of Thymeleaf.

Comment: I found solution:

add before link "/"

Topic should be close

Comment: You may want to post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: add before link "/" Topic should be close:)